# Unrecognised name: when using UNNEST WHERE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I’m trying to filter during an unnest in BigQuery as per [this blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-use-select-from-unnest-to-analyze-multiple-parameters-in-bigquery-for-analytics-5838f7a004c2), but I can’t get the pattern working.

The reproducible example in the blog works really nicely.

```
SELECT event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, 
  event_params
FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003`
WHERE event_name = "level_complete_quickplay"
```

[image: BigQuery console showing array event_params]

```
SELECT event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, 
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE key = "value") AS score
FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003`
WHERE event_name = "level_complete_quickplay"
```

[image: BigQuery console showing unnested and filtered component of event_params]

When I try this on my own table I get the error `Unrecognised name:`. I've tried to reproduce the error in a toy table, `nested_seq`.

```
WITH sequences AS (
  SELECT 
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] AS some_numbers
    UNION ALL SELECT [2, 4, 8, 16, 32] AS some_numbers
    UNION ALL SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers
), 
-- table containing repeated record
nested_seq AS (
  SELECT 
    some_numbers,
    some_numbers[OFFSET(1)] AS offset_1,
    some_numbers[ORDINAL(1)] AS ordinal_1
  FROM sequences
)
-- transformation to extract single value from array
SELECT *
FROM nested_seq
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
  some_numbers
  FROM UNNEST(some_numbers)
  WHERE some_numbers = 2)
-- Unrecognized name: some_numbers at [21:19]
```

What I'm expecting is that elements of `some_numbers` can be extracted so that I can unnest a nested array without increasing the number of rows.

| Row | some_numbers | offset_1 | ordinal_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | null | 10 | 5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... elements of some_numbers can be extracted so that I can unnest a nested array without increasing the number of rows.

Consider below "fix"

```
WITH sequences AS (
  SELECT 
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] AS some_numbers
    UNION ALL SELECT [2, 4, 8, 16, 32] AS some_numbers
    UNION ALL SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers
)
SELECT # some_numbers,
  (SELECT some_number
    FROM t.some_numbers some_number
    WHERE some_number = 2
  ) some_number,
  some_numbers[OFFSET(1)] AS offset_1,
  some_numbers[ORDINAL(1)] AS ordinal_1
FROM sequences t
```

with output

[image]